# 100% height with margin while keeping width constraints for DIV in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I want a DIV insider another one (which I don't want to change for some reasons) to be

- centered horizontally
- width: 70%, but not more than 800px and not less than 300px
- height: 100%, but 50px margin at the top, and 20px margin at the bottom
- displayed correctly with IE9+, modern desktop browsers and iOS 6+ Safari

I could get it working for all properties but the height using this CSS ("child" is target DIV):

```
#child{
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width:800px;
    min-width:300px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:block;
}
```

The height margins are respected, but the content is stretched, and so a scroll bar appears, what want to prevent.

Please see a full example [at this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6we2axp/).

Do you have any idea how this could be fixed?

I know that there are many questions about "how to achieve 100% height and margins", but I didn't find one that considered a variable width.

Comment: I couldn't understand your key problem?

Comment: Can you add top/bottom padding of 50/20px to parent?

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please add a sketch of what your expected output should look like compared to what it looks currently like in the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning to get the height right:

```
#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This requires adding `position: relative` to `#parent` but if it is the only child of the body then you can avoid it. This takes care of the *which I don't want to change for some reasons* part of your question.

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/u6we2axp/4/)

Answer (score 4):

That's because the margins are added to the height of the element.

I updated the fiddle by adding padding to the parent and removing margin to the child.

I also used the box-sizing property to make it take the padding into account when computing the height of the parent :

```
#parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6we2axp/2/